# Kendo Ui Editor Image Browser CSS

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui

I implemented Kendo UI editor with ImageBrowser functionality in my asp.net mvc application.

Kendo UI editor looks good but the ImageBrowser popup does have any css applied to it.

Is there any class using which we can apply CSS to the imagebrowser.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you have loaded all the necessary CSS files? The ImageBrowser should be styled as well as the Kendo UI Editor.

Have you checked this documentation article:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/appearance-styling